# Short way to solve integration of unique problem of rational function which cannot be solved by substitution

Tags: integration

Here is the problem:
Integration of 
$$\int\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x^2+x+2}}.$$

I started by completing the square and then substituting but it became too complicated.

So I want to solve in a shorter way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the Euler substution.

Comment: You've asked a similar question 2 hours ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249491/indefinite-integration-of-int-frac11-sqrtx22x2dx/3249507#3249507

Comment: Sir is not euler substitution used in R(x,ax^2+bx+c)

Comment: I think the euler substitution will not work here whats your opinion sir

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $$1-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$$ and you will get
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{1-x^2-x-2}$$

Comment: Sir please tell will going by euler substitution give right result.

Comment: We have $$\sqrt{x^2+x+2}=t+x$$ so $$x=\frac{t^2-2}{1-2t}$$ and $$dx=-\frac{2(t^2-t+2)}{(2t-1)^2}dt$$

Comment: Sir thanks for the procedure but i actually want to know that is it right to do here since there no independent term of 'x' here

Comment: You have $$\sqrt{x^2+x+2}=t+\frac{t^2-2}{1-2t}$$

Comment: Ok sir can we use euler form in this one also                                                          integration of 1/(1+(x^2+2x+2)^(1/2)) i tried in this one but i cant get the right answer